# Xamarin android - Application datas

Tags: android, xamarin, android-sdcard, android-storage

My Application save custom data on the device in order to use it in the application. I save them at the root directory of the device and th directory is hidden (.XXXXX).

It works very well but i need to be able to move my Application on the SD card too, i tried to do it and my application is moved properly but not my application datas (save on the device root directory). Seems normal i guess.

Can someone tell me where can i save the datas in order to be able to move them at the same time when i use the android functionnality in setting (move to SD card) ? And can someone telle me what is the method in order to retrieve my applicaiton path on the device when application is insatlled on the device, and my application path on the sd card when application is installed on the sd card ? Tried somes methods but i didn't found the good one.

Thank you